# Zcash wallet generation

Tags: address-generation, zcash

How to generate Zcash address and private key by a mnemonic seed, in nodejs or python?
Is there some lib like bitcore-lib or ethereum-bip44?

Answer (score 1):

Zcash transparent addresses can be generated in the usual [BIP 44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) way. There is a Zcash `coin_type` defined in [SLIP 44](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md), which can be used with any standard Bitcoin library. The resulting transparent addresses just need to be re-encoded with the [Zcash transparent address prefix for mainnet](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L140-L141).

There is currently no library for generating Zcash shielded addresses deterministically. We are working on [ZIP 32](https://github.com/zcash/zips/pull/157) which will define how to generate Sprout and Sapling shielded addresses from a seed. In practice, this will be the same seed used for transparent addresses.